# Altering the content of a react component manually

Tags: reactjs

I ended up in a quite awkward situation where I have to manually alter a React component before it get's rendered.

I'm using draft.js and have created a CompositeDecorator.

The decorator returns a react object that is styled just the way I want, but I need to replace the text of that component before I render it.

I can see that the object has a `props` property, that has a `text` property inside it. This is the text I want to change, but that property is readonly.

I can't do it the normal react way, since I don't control the part of the application that actually creates this component.

Are there any way to change this property, or to create a copy of this component that is an exact copy except for the text property?

Comment: You can't change props. You have to create a new component and pass new prop value to it.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko - The problem is that I didn't create the component in the first place, so I don't know how to create it. Any way to copy the other component, and change the value in the copy?

Comment: There are several ways to do that in React that I'm aware of: 1) Pass props from parent component from the top to the bottom 2) Pass props from global application state if you are using Redux (any other Flux library) 3) Changing component state will also trigger re-rendering but these changes are initiated from the component internally. Maybe there are other ways, I'm new to React and that's so far what I understand about React flow while was trying to solve similar problems.